# Difference between 'Uplink' and Port Speed

Tags: host

Some web-hosts use the term `uplink` and some other hosts use `port speed`, relating to servers. Why? Is there any difference?

Answer (score 3):

Port Speed refers the speed of data transferring in the hardware, and UpLink is related to the speed of data transferring from client side to server, whose speed can be controlled by the administrator.

Answer (score 2):

Port Speed is the actual physical link speed, it's symmetric in regards to sending and receiving speed. Most providers administratively limit the actual throughput of that port. The throughput can be asymmetrically limited to a certain outgoing speed (the Uplink speed) and a certain incoming speed (Downlink speed). Further there may be other limits on data throughput, be careful to know what your buying and that it fits your needs.